# How Does One Increase the Holding Current of an SCR?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I'm an EE and I've spent most of my career in FPGA programming, so please forgive if this question is dumb.

For most of the SCR data sheets I've read, the holding current is on the order of 1% of the maximum DC current.

I want the holding current to be closer to 50% of the maximum DC current.

What I *really* want is for the SCR to shut off on its own, without external components, which means that we change the device design. For example, I already know that external transistors can shunt current away from the SCR so that it turns off. However, I am trying to eliminate those components.

I would love it if someone can tell me, "Increase variable X until Y > Z," and things of that nature. Pointing me to the equations I should focus on would also be useful.

Here are my questions:

1.) Is this even possible?

2.) If it's possible, what are some things that a semiconductor expert would to in order to achieve it?

3.) Are there solid state reasons why nobody does this? For instance, does doing such a thing necessarily mean that device life will be 99% shorter? Or is it more of an industry standard because you get better efficiency out of a power converter by making the holding current as low as possible?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. The holding current is (apart from a slight dependence on the forward voltage) a constant for a given device, while the current that is flowing through the device is a circuit property. So if you pick a much larger SCR with a much larger holding current, then the ratio between the actual circuit current and the holding current will increase, won't it? It's just a very inefficient way of doing this as it requires a much larger (and more expensive) SCR.

Comment: you will more likely to get an answer here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FlatterMann what equations govern the holding current? I want to design an SCR with the desired holding current.

Comment: The holding current is a function of the area of the SCR. If you make it larger in area, I believe, then you get a proportionally larger holding current. Or do you mean you want to design an actual semiconductor device rather than use one that you can buy and you want to know how to change the doping and gate geometry? In that case I misunderstood and will let someone answer who knows how to design SCRs. With stock components you can, of course, simulate an SCR with two bipolar transistors. In that case you probably just have to reduce the base current for the larger one with a resistor.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: @FlatterMann Can you move your comment to an answer so I can accept it? Also, can you expound on the use of two bipolar transistors to simulate an SCR? I would love to use two BJT's and a resistor to effectively get a programmable SCR :)

Comment: Apologies, I could give you an actual answer with a circuit diagram and a simulation, but I won't. I consider that kind of circuit very bad practice. SCRs have their uses in circuits where the turn-off is not critical but I wouldn't suggest using them in this kind of scenario. If you want a controlled turn-off, I would suggest the use of a Mosfet or a bipolar transistor with a current sense resistor, a discriminator and a latch. This is literally a nickel's worth of electronics and it will perform exactly what you want with high reliability and negligible temperature dependence.